# How to make a 1:2 UnUn

Tags: antenna-construction, transmission-line, transformer

Does anyone have a drawing or instructions on how to make a 1:2 unun like the one in the picture below ?

I searched this question on this site and on the internet with no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this at [this page by PA0ROB](http://pa0rob.vandenhoff.info/index.php/article/unun-impedance-transformer-end-fed), which you should absolutely check out. He's focused on higher ratio ununs, but shows the general design principles that you can use to make a 2:1.

One of the key principles is that **the impedance transformation is the square of the turn/winding ratio**, so you're looking to wind a 1.4:1 ratio (since 1.4 * 1.4 ~ 2).

With the ratio math out of the way, now you can focus on translating that to physical windings using the above page as a template.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: That site is hard to follow and a bit confusing - Question - a 1:1 unun with bifilar windings is very straight forward with say 3 turns on primary and secondary using wires twisted together. What do you do when there are are 3 x 1.41 windings on the primary 50 ohms side and 3 turns on the secondary 25 ohms side ? what happens with the bifilar part as now the turns aren't equal ? do you just have the extra windings not bifilar ?

Comment: Is this right ? - forget bifilar, wind let's say 14 turns of enamelled copper wire onto a type 43 ferrite ring, connect one end of the winding to the grounds of primary and secondary ground connections, connect the other end of the coil to 50 ohms primary active connection , tap a point at 10 turns from the ground end of the winding and connect that to the 25 ohms secondary active connection ...

Comment: you've got it, 14:10 gets you where you need to be. So does 7:5. You may want to experiment to see which provides better power handling and SWR. You may even find that 3:2 is close enough.

Comment: Thanks Marc much appreciated.

Comment: I made 2 x 4 element 28 MHz yagis, tuned them separately both for 50 ohms so the SWR was perfect, then connected them in parallel and connected the antennas between ground and the the tap at 10 turns, and the coax going to the radio across the 14 turns, and the SWR went up to about 10, any ideas what i did wrong ?

Comment: Bring this over to the chat, hard to do this in comments... here's [a link to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11162/ham-shack)

Answer (score 1):

@webmarc mentioned the ratio 1:1.4, which is an approximation of 1 to the square root of 2, which is approximately equal to 1.4142135..., but how do you approximate this infinite number with a finite number of turns?

@Andrew mentioned the ratio 10:14, which is good, but there are other numbers of turns that could be handy to know.

If you want as few turns as possible, you could go with the ratio 3:2. (3/2)² = 2.25, so you end up with a 1:2.25 transformer which is sort of close and might be good enough for some applications.

6:4 is the same ratio as 3:2, but with higher numbers, but if you want more turns you might as well go with 7:5. This ratio is significantly closer, and (7/5)² = 1.96.

If you want an even closer approximation, the only better approximation with less than 70 turns is 17:12, with (17/12)² ≈ 2.007.

I can't see any reason anyone would need a more accurate approximation than that, since in practice other factors like the precise way you mount the wire on the toroid or how tightly you wind the turns most likely will affect the result more.

If you want more turns, simply use a multiple of one of the suggested numbers!

Hope this helps someone!